# Laravel Scout/Meilisearch error when using filters/where clause

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-scout, meilisearch

When I try to use a where clause after the search method I get this:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cY2aA.png)

That's my Product model:
[Product model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7sq0.png)

I've tried two methods to get the products of a specific store_id:

[This one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbhwz.png) and [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bB1d.png) (sorry for not using the code formatting I'm too dumb for that)

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using PHP 8.0.10, Arch Linux, Meilisearch 0.22.0, Laravel 8.4, Laravel Scout 9.2 and meilisearch-php 0.19.1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! The error explains you have to add the attribute you want to filter by to the filterableAttributes in the MeiliSearch settings: https://docs.meilisearch.com/reference/features/filtering_and_faceted_search.html

Comment: Oh thanks, just in case someone needs it, I decided to make a command (meilisearch:update) and your handle function looks like this:                               $client = new Client(config('scout.meilisearch.host')); $client->index('products')->updateFilterableAttributes(['id', 'name', 'sku', 'store_id']);